# SSH and Screen with a Python script

Tags: python, ssh, operating-system, gnu-screen

I'm trying to do the following from a python script:

1. connect to remote server
2. in that remote server create a Screen
3. in that screen run a few commands
4. exit

So I try the following:

```
import os
os.system('ssh -t -t myname@server')
os.system('nice -11 screen')
```

However, the last command does not execute on the server. I get into the server, but have no connection to it from the python script anymore. What I want to do now is create a screen session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
import os
os.system('ssh -t -t myname@myserver "nice -11 screen"')
```

This leaves you at the screen.

Or if you just want to run a few commands:

```
import os
os.system('ssh -t -t myname@myserver "ls && pwd"')
```

This runs both these commands, then exits.

**Edit:**

The following will leave you at a shell prompt:

```
os.system('ssh -t -t myname@myserver "nice -11 screen -U"')
```

The following will run a command, then leave you at a shell prompt:

```
os.system('ssh -t -t myname@myserver "ls > ~/x.txt && nice -11 screen -U"')
```

Comment: The problem is that the connection is immediately lost after I run any of the commands...

Comment: @ArashSaidi: See my edits...they will leave you at a prompt if that's what you want.